# Primefaces schedule component - customize event label

Tags: primefaces

**Primefaces 4**

**Description:**

There is a component *p:schedule* which shows events. Look at this showcase [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf).

As you see event label consists of two elements:
- hour
- title

These variables are set this way:

```java
new DefaultScheduleEvent("Some title", dateBegin, dateEnd);
```

**Problem 1:**

This set of information is not enought for me. I would like to show a bit more, and without hour. For for every event three lines: event title in the first line, some name in the second line, phone number in the third line.

Is there any way to do this?

**Problem 2:**

Let's say I like to show only max five events and link below these events if there are more than five events. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not possible**

Primefaces uses FullCalendar, javascript library written by Adam Shaw. I've checked FullCalendar source code and this is not possible atm. Primefaces does not provide more complex event data model than this library itself.

So once again. You cannot have customized event data shown out of the box.